# Logoff local users if they close the rdp session

Tags: rdp, gpo

I have a new project for my domain and the local users...

My goals:

- Switch the local explorer.exe to mstsc.exe, i only want a black screen with the rdp login (i already finished it)
- Automaticaly logoff local users, if they closed the rdp session

The challenge:

- How can i automatically logoff local users if the explorer.exe & mstsc.exe dont run?

Answer (score 0):

One easy (but dirty) solution I see is a sheduled task running every 1-2 minutes that checkes is both processes are running. In case where explorer.exe is present but mstsc.exe is not - force a reboot or logoff.